# Energy absorbed by the condenser

Tags: circuit-analysis, energy

If the current \$i=0\$ the total energy absorbed is:

\$E_{tot}=E_C+E_L\$, where \$E_C\$ is the energy absorbed by the condenser and \$E_L\$ that absorbed by the inductor.

Now:

- \$E_C=\frac{1}{2}C v^2_C(t)=\frac{1}{2} C \Big(\frac{1}{C} \int i\ dt\Big)^2=\frac{1}{2C}(\int i\ dt)^2\$.

  Since \$i=0\$, it should be \$0\$ too, but my book says it isn't zero. Why?
- \$E_L=\frac{1}{2}L i^2_L(t)=\frac{1}{2} L \cdot 0 =0\$

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fjHkqo.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: I think since the 1940s or so people call them capacitors...

Comment: **Ec = 0.5Cv^2** and **El=0.5Li^2** You are missing the square exponent over that voltage and that current!

Comment: @LorenzoDonati Yes, a mistake. I'm correcting it.

Comment: @PlasmaHH It's a translation thing, I believe.

Comment: @EugeneSh., and it will help OP in the future to know the up-to-date English term for *condensador* or whatever s/he's translating from.

Comment: @EugeneSh. I do think so, too. Here in Italy we use the term *condensatore* (condenser) and any attempt to introduce an almost-homograph *capacitore* failed miserably (since *condensatore* is an Italian word, whereas "capacitore" is not and seems too weird, probably). Still, I scold my students when they write "condenser" instead of "capacitor" in English. English technical terms *must be known* by technicians (never seen a datasheet written in Italian ;-).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you have your energy formulas wrong!

\$E_C(t) = \dfrac 1 2 C \, v_C^2(t) \$

and

\$E_L(t) = \dfrac 1 2 L \, i_L^2(t) \$

But this inconsequential.

Your error lies in the integration, because you are neglecting initial conditions on the capacitor. The problem is that the correct formula to express the voltage on a capacitor given the current is:

\$
v_C(t) = \dfrac 1 C \int_{-\infty}^t i(\tau) \, d\tau =
\dfrac 1 C \int_{t_0}^t i(\tau)\,d\tau + v_C(t_0)
\$

where \$t_0\$ is some arbitrary time instant before the time you are evaluating the voltage for, i.e. \$ t_0<t\$.

So, even if the current is 0 in the interval \$[t_0,t]\$, you still have a voltage \$v_C(t_0)\$ across the cap which accounts for its stored energy. The current in the capacitor accounts only for the *voltage change* between the two instants \$t_0\$ and \$t\$. If the current is 0, the voltage won't change, but if it was initially non-zero it will remain the same, as the energy stored in it (bar leakage, in practice).

**EDIT**

(To be more precise, in response to a comment)

\$
v_C(t_0) = \dfrac 1 C \int_{-\infty}^{t_0} i(\tau)\,d\tau 
\$

The integral represents the net charge accumulated on the reference plate of the capacitor in the interval \$(-\infty,t_0]\$. This model implicitly assumes that the capacitor was not charged initially, i.e. looooong time before \$t_0\$. To be more specific, it is assumed that \$v_C(-\infty)=0\$.

If you wonder where this relation comes from, it is from the "inversion" of the *capacitor V-I relationship*:

\$
i(t) = C \dfrac{dv_C(t)}{dt}
\$

which, assuming i(t) is a known function, is an ordinary linear non-homogenous 1st order differential equation of simple type. You can solve it using the method of separation of variables:

\$
dv_C(t) = \dfrac 1 C i(t)\, dt
\$

Which can be integrated over the interval \$(-\infty,t]\$, yielding:

\$
v_C(t) = \dfrac 1 C \int_{-\infty}^{t} i(\tau)\,d\tau 
\$

Comment: This is because: \$v_C(t)=\frac{1}{C}\int_{-\infty}^{t} i(\tau) d\tau = \frac{1}{C}[\int_{-\infty}^{0^-} i(\tau) d\tau + \int_{0}^{+\infty} i(\tau) d\tau]=\frac{1}{C}\int_{-\infty}^{0^-} i(\tau) d\tau+\frac{1}{C}\int_{0}^{+\infty} i(\tau) d\tau=v_C(0^-)+\frac{1}{C}\int_{0}^{+\infty} i(\tau) d\tau\$. Right?

Comment: No (the second step of your derivation is wrong). See my further edit.

Comment: It looks like your expression is the same as what I wrote, except for the integration bound. I used \$0\$, you used a generic \$t_0\$. Is it correct?

Comment: Oh, and I also wrote (by mistake) \$+\infty\$ in place of \$t\$.

Comment: Taking your mistake into account, then yes (almost) you are correct, assuming \$t_0=0\$. I said "almost" because your use of \$0^{-}\$ is inconsequential, unless your integrand functions contains Dirac's delta functions, but that is another can of worms.

Answer (score 1):

Lower case i usually represents i(t) at some specific instant in time.

If i(t) = 0 at some specific time t, that tells you nothing about the voltage across the capacitor. All you know is that the voltage across the capacitor plus the voltage across the inductor must add up to the voltage across the two lower terminals (whatever that is).

Suppose the capacitor is charged to 1V. Then the energy stored in the capacitor is C/2 with i(t) = 0 for all t. This is the arbitrary constant that you left out when you (incorrectly) did the integration.

Energy in the capacitor is \$CV^2/2\$
Energy in the inductor is \$LI^2/2\$

If you know that Vc(t) = 0 at time = 0 and that i(t) = 0 for 0 \$\le\$ t < \$\infty\$ then you can say that the energy stored in the capacitor is 0 for any t \$\ge\$ 0;